# How to avoid/evade garbage-collection bug resulting in NSClipViewBackingLayer being over-retained

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, garbage-collection

Problem:

Suspected crash in garbage collector.

Question:

How do you deal with this?

Is there anything else I can do other than filing a bug report? 
An obvious solution would be: "do not resize the view", but that would hurt functionality too much.
Would it be useful to prevent the views from being redrawn until resizing is done?
I tried [… removeFromSuperView], then resize, then [… addSubView:…]; That doesn't help.

How can I avoid/evade this problem?

The error message:

```
malloc: garbage block 0x2008a71a0(_NSClipViewBackingLayer[128]) was over-retained during finalization, refcount = 1
This could be an unbalanced CFRetain(), or CFRetain() balanced with -release.
Break on auto_zone_resurrection_error() to debug.
malloc: fatal resurrection error for garbage block 0x2008a71a0(_NSClipViewBackingLayer[128]): over-retained during finalization, refcount = 1
```

The thread that is crashing is a background thread from the garbage collector called "Garbage Collection Work Queue".

When I break on auto_zone_resurrection_error and do a stack backtrace, I get:

```
0  0x00007fff8094aba4 in auto_zone_resurrection_error ()
1  0x00007fff80959ce6 in Auto::Zone::handle_overretained_garbage ()
2  0x00007fff8095a0b4 in Auto::Zone::free_garbage ()
3  0x00007fff80944bd3 in auto_collect_internal ()
4  0x00007fff809450cd in auto_collection_work ()
5  0x00007fff80626284 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
6  0x00007fff80604df2 in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
7  0x00007fff80604c54 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
8  0x00007fff806047fe in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
9  0x00007fff80604128 in _pthread_wqthread ()
10 0x00007fff80603fc5 in start_wqthread ()
```

I suspect the problem is related to the IKImageViews that are being resized. Why do I suspect this?

1. Taming IKImageView has been a royal PITA from start to finish (under-documented, buggy, lots of features but no access to them).
2. The crash occurs during resizing of a NSScrollView with 3 IKImageViews.
3. The Main thread is halted at [IKImageView zoomImageToFit:]

---

### Update in response to @bbum and @Peter Hosey

I was able to not fix, but mostly circumvent the crashing garbage collector.

1. Enabled: MallocStackLoggingNoCompact AUTO_REFERENCE_COUNT_LOGGING
2. reproduced crash
3. break on auto_zone_resurrection_error
4. get address of over-retained block (0x20242cde0 in this case, just for reference to the below)

info malloc 0x20242cde0 then produced *a lot* of output on this address (290 Kb of plain text). The most frequent mention was: NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView

As I expected something seemed to be happening during drawing of an NSView.

I subsequently tried Instruments as suggested by @Peter. This produces a rather long history of allocated objects. I needed to look at the Crash Report to get the address of the over-retained block (while running Instruments there is no output to the console and Instruments doesn't immediately indicate which is the offending block (or I don't know where to look, which is entirely possible)).

```
#       Object Address  Category        Creation Time   Live    Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
659531  0x20242cde0 CFRunLoopObserver   00:21.577.876       128 AppKit      -[NSApplication setWindowsNeedUpdate:]
659532  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.352.081       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659533  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.352.328       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659534  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.351.892       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659535  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.321.389       128 QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::add_root(CALayer*)
659536  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.321.380   •   128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659537  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.351.710       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659538  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.320.100       128 QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::add_root(CALayer*)
659539  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.351.433       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659540  0x20242cde0 _NSClipViewBackingLayer 00:26.293.575   •   128 AppKit      -[NSClipView makeBackingLayer]
659541  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.293.601   •   128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659542  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.351.311   •   128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659543  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.294.761   •   128 QuartzCore  CAViewSetLayer
659544  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.294.764   •   128 QuartzCore  CA::Context::set_layer(CALayer*)
659545  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.294.767   •   128 QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::add_root(CALayer*)
659546  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.320.091   •   128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659547  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.347.524       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659548  0x20242cde0 NSConcreteNotification  00:20.730.342       64  Foundation  +[NSConcreteNotification newTempNotificationWithName:object:userInfo:]
659549  0x20242cde0 CFNumber        00:16.433.727       32  Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:]
659550  0x20242cde0 NSRectSet       00:20.750.542       64  AppKit      -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:]
659551  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:21.189.518       128 Foundation  -[NSMutableIndexSet _ensureRangeCapacity:]
659552  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.322.017   •   128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659553  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.356.013       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659554  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.356.440       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659555  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.404.886   •   128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659556  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.404.887       128 QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::add_root(CALayer*)
659557  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.356.824       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659558  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.299.972       128 QuartzCore  CALayerCollectAllLayers(X::List<CALayer*>*, CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, x_heap_struct*)
659559  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.322.025       128 QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::add_root(CALayer*)
659560  0x20242cde0 CFString (store)    00:23.702.683       128 CoreUI      CUIRenderer::CreateImage(long, CUIDescriptor const*, CGRect*, double*, unsigned short*, unsigned char*)
659561  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.334.571       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659562  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.332.018       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659563  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.357.443       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659564  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.322.144   •   128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659565  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.322.150       128 QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::add_root(CALayer*)
659566  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.315.651       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659567  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.333.920       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659568  0x20242cde0 CFString        00:15.204.217       32  Foundation  -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]
659569  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.313.695       128 QuartzCore  CALayerCollectLayers_(CALayer*, _CALayerIvars*, collect_layers_closure*)
659570  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.588.328   •   128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659571  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.325.239   •   128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659572  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.367.861       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659573  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.325.742       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659574  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.333.519       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659575  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.361.547       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659576  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.367.493       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659577  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.333.125       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659578  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.362.011       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659579  0x20242cde0 CFBasicHash     00:16.269.569       64  Foundation  +[NSBundle preferredLocalizationsFromArray:forPreferences:]
659580  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.362.442       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659581  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:22.918.104       128 libauto.dylib   Auto::foreach_block_do(auto_zone_cursor*, void (*)(void*, void*), void*)
659582  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.326.245       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659583  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.363.024       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659584  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.326.401       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659585  0x20242cde0 CFString (store)    00:16.808.912       128 Foundation  -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]
659586  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.326.792       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659587  0x20242cde0 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:26.367.083       128 QuartzCore  CALayerTransactionFlagsLocation_(CALayer*, CA::Transaction*, _CALayerIvars*)
659588  0x20242cde0 CFString (store)    00:22.935.991       128 CoreUI      CUIRenderer::CreateImage(long, CUIDescriptor const*, CGRect*, double*, unsigned short*, unsigned char*)
659589  0x20242ce00 Malloc 128 Bytes    00:20.100.480       128 Foundation  allocateCollectableUnscannedWeakStorageWithSentinel
```

The object was not being over-retained in my code, which made it difficult to exactly pinpoint what was going wrong where. However from the above it became clear that something was going wrong during Core Animation.

I had noticed that it was easiest to reproduce the crash when I repeatedly resized the window, i.e. make it larger and then somewhat more larger. I suspect that the crash is caused by the second resize occurring while the IKImageViews inside the NSScrollView are still animating their contents in response to the first resize.

Partial "solution":

I already was not LiveResizing but updating the scrollview *after* the window had been resized.

I now block resizing of the main window for 1 second after each windowDidEndLiveResize. This strongly reduces the frequency of occurrence of the crash, but sadly not completely eliminates it.

(The IKImageView animation duration is about 300 msecs, but blocking resize for too short a duration is ineffective. Presumable GC is active for some time after then animation finished).

**Question:** can I disable animation on IKImageView completely?
I tried the undocumented private method [someIKImageView setAnimates:NO], but that does nothing.

Why does this not completely eliminate the crash?
I think because I can still trigger resize notifications even though I am (trying to) block window resizing (by temporarily hiding the resize glyph and fixing max/min size).

**Question:** Is there a better way to prevent a window from resizing?
(I read this blog: [vgable.com/blog/2008/04/11/nswindow-setresizable](http://vgable.com/blog/2008/04/11/nswindow-setresizable/))

[PS 1: info gc-roots 0x20242cde0 would just hang (I waited 10 minutes; no output; prompt never returned).]

[PS 2: this was also useful (@bbum's site) [using-malloc-to-debug-memory-misuse-in-cocoa](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/01/10/using-malloc-to-debug-memory-misuse-in-cocoa/)]

Comment: Just so you know: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: And I feared I was being too direct. Thanks (?) for pointing that out. I have edited the question.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you (I'm using an `IKImageView` which seems to work fine in a garbage-collected app, but it's not inside a scroll view) but you might want to check out Apple's [tips for debugging garbage collected apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECGC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, file a bug.  This most likely a bug in IKImageView.  Yuck.

Next, turn on malloc stack logging (see `man malloc`) and also set `AUTO_REFERENCE_COUNT_LOGGING` to `YES`, you can use `malloc_history` (or `info malloc`) in GDB to see exactly where the object was retained.

---

Sounds like a bug in IK and CoreAnimation;  please file it.  Namely, if there are outstanding animations occurring during resize, then -- effectively -- there are transactions in flight.  When the collector sees that the object is garbage, CA coincidentally creates a new strong reference via CFRetain() while the object is being finalized.

In theory, you should be able to hold a strong reference -- CFRetain or stick it in a global array or something -- to keep the object from being collected.  Then, once the object has been removed from the render tree and all animations are truly done, you could remove the object's strong reference and it'll go away without complaint [hopefully -- there may still be a bug that'll cause issue even with this].

And, really, please file a bug and point to this SO question in your bug.  This should not be happening.

Comment: Would the History feature in Instruments's Allocations instrument be useful here? (I've never tried it on a GC process.)

Comment: Updated the question in response to @bbum and @Peter

Comment: Yah -- the history feature in Allocations should work, too.  You might need to set the AUTO environment variable manually, though (I can't remember which checkbox does what exactly).\